# Set JTable size in GridBaglayout to increase dynamically according to number of rows

Tags: java, swing, jtable, layout-manager, gridbaglayout

I am trying to add data to a JTable taken from user. My insertion query works fine (printed success message to console to check) but when the values are inserted, they are not displayed in the table but a strange new column is displayed looking like a slit rather than an actual row. Please refer to the  [error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ik7Me.png)

I have tried the following:`

```
    Object[] cols = {"col 1","col 2","col 3"};
    private DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel();
    private JTable table = new JTable(model);
    private JScrollPane sp = new JScrollPane(table); 

    gbc.gridx=0;
    gbc.gridy++;
    gbc.weightx=1;
    gbc.weighty=1;
    gbc.fill=GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
    gbc.gridwidth = 8;
    gbc.gridheight = 4;
    model.setColumnIdentifiers(cols);
    gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.VERTICAL;
    gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;`
    add(sp,gbc);
```

I even watched youtube tutorials on the same, and did exactly what they did. But my data is not displayed at all. That is why I think the problem lies with the GridBagLayout
Can anyone help?

Comment: hard without [mcve]... but try `table.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_ALL_COLUMNS)`, or/and `table.doLayout()` (after adding data); also do not forget to `validate` or `pack` the frame (depending on use case)

Comment: _I even watched youtube tutorials_ If you are willing to consider something that is ___not___ a YouTube video as a valid learning resource, then take a look at [How to Use Tables](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) Also, I have never displayed a `JTable` in a container that uses a `GridBagLayout` layout manager. Maybe also have a look at [Laying Out Components Within a Container](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html).

Comment: I have solved the problem. all that was needed was to replace                              
    gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.VERTICAL;
    gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;                                                                                with gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH; and that was it. :D